# python assistance with 'if filename[-4]=="B" '

Tags: python

can anyone tell me what the purpose of the ***if filename[-4]=="B"*** is in an if statement in some code I came across plz?

(Using py 2.7.5)

Cheers, Peter

Comment: Have you looked at the tutorials or the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This somewhat depends on the context, but it effectively means "the element of the variable 'filename' at the fourth position from the end."

So, if `filename` is a string with the value of `'Test string.'` then `filename[-4]` will be `'i'`.

In this particular case, the expression would evaluate to `False`, because "i" is not "B".

Answer (score 1):

negative index in python refers to reverse indexing. i.e) Traversing the string/list in a reverse manner 
Eg)

```
>>> a="hello"
>>> a[-1]
'o'
>>> a[-2]
'l'
```

So, a[-4] refers to the fourth character from the last. In your example, the fourth element from the last is checked to be 'B'. The if block is executed if `filename[-4]` is 'B'

Comment: appreciate your response too. Cheers